# django CommandError: One or more models did not validate:

Tags: python, django

The Model class are generated by the django `inspectdb` and i can see the Id field, this is converted from the Legacy tables, the table cant be altered here,

```
class workFlowTemplate(models.Model):
    rev = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    revtype = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    **id = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)**
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True,primary_key=False)
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'workflow_template'
```

the problem is when i try to run the django it throws error

```
CommandError: One or more models did not validate:
pHApp.workflowtemplate: "id": You can't use "id" as a field name, because each model automatically gets an "id" field if none of the fields have primary_key=True. You need to either remove/rename your "id" field or add primary_key=True to a field.
```

**Note**

```
the id is not primary key here in this case,
```

When i tries to change
id = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True,**primary_key=False)**

the Issue still remains the same, and same error is repeated again, how to avoid this Issue ?

Comment: If `id` is not your primary key, what is?

Comment: @DanielRoseman id is just a INTEGER field in the database, and there is no key attached to it,this is legacy database, where id is used as non-primary key

Answer (score 2):

A model must have a primary key, so you need specify a primary key field, like this:

```
my_primary_key = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
id = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
```

then it won’t add the automatic id column and you will not receive this error.

Answer (score 0):

Column `id` is adding by django by default, if you did not specified another field as PK.
In your case, you specified `id` as your field, but you did not specified what field should be a primary key.
Solution - set another field as primary key since you can not rename `id`

Comment: Well, as I know you can not live without primary key. What you need is to create one, or you have no permission to modify database?